# Can't open Publish dialog in Visual Studio 2015 (ASP.NET 5 web application)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure

We have an ASP.NET web application already deployed to Azure. I'm trying to create a new development virtual machine (using VirtualBox). Everything seems to work fine. I can run the project locally, but when I click on Publish, I just get a comment in the Output window: "**The build has been canceled**".

The same project using the same version of Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 can be deployed without any problem from the other development PCs (they are NOT virtual machines, don't know if it matter or not).

I use the latest version of all extensions installed. I have 'repaired' my Visual Studio Installation, just in case.

Any suggestions?

Note : I just tried to publish a new, empty ASP.NET 5 Web Application. I got the same "The build has been canceled" message.

Comment: ever figure this out?

Comment: No, I don't use VM anymore for this.

Comment: Here's how I got it fixed:
(1) get frustrated on a Friday, trying to restart VS, the machine, delete random files
(2) give up and go home for the weekend
(3) show up on monday
And then things worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be VirtualBox (or Visual Studio 2015 in VirtualBox). I can't publish any website from any VirtualBox VM but I can publish all of them from the PC where the VM is running.